# Use a RaiseEvent statement to raise an event VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, aforge, raiseevent

I get this error:

> Error  1   'Public Event NewFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As
>      AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly.
>      Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
>      C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stream\Stream\Form1.vb
>     9   9   Stream

My code is:

[image]

How I can solve this?

Comment: put your code here rather than an image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a VB buff, but I don't think that how you subscribe to events in VB.  Try:

```
Dim stream As New MJPEGStream("...")
AddHandler stream.NewFrame, AddressOf Me.video_NewFrame
...
```